# Retrieving Environment Variables using Curl Command

Tags: apache, curl

I am using a curl command to retrieve the value of the environment variable in Apache, but its not working, what part in the payload is wrong or missing in the syntax? Using Linux

curl 'http://localhost:8080/rest/' -H '${env:USER}'

I try curl 'http://localhost:8080/rest/' -H '${env:USER}'

Comment: What shell is this? `${env:USER}` is fairly unusual. Normally it's just `$USER`

Comment: it does not display the env variable using env:$USER

Comment: I also tried 
curl 'http://localhost:8080/rest/' -H "${env:HOME}"

Comment: I'm asking again. What shell is this? In normal shells such as bash/sh or ksh an env variable is just a variable. So it is not `env:$USER` it is `$USER`. The command is normally `curl $URL -H $USER`. What shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using /bin/bash

Comment: The application is running in localhost 8080 and the curl command I used but nothing is returned:
curl 'http://localhost:8080/rest/' -H $USER I also tried wrapping  the variable with hard quotes, soft quotes -H '$USER'  or -H "$USER" and nothing is returned on the terminal. Thank you

Comment: You forgot `http://`?

Comment: Ah. Also `kira` or whatever the value of `$USER` is is not a valid header. HTTP headers have the format of `Header-Name: header_value`. For example, to send a custom user agent string you would do `curl http://localhost:8080 -H 'User-Agent: my custom HTTP client version 1.0'`. You are not sending a valid header. I don't think this has anything to do with environment variables but simply you're making a bad/malformed request

Comment: ... Presumably you want something like `curl http://localhost:8080/test -H "User: $USER"` but I don't know what header your server is expecting